# DFA Minimization: Finding all equivalence classes of $\mathsf{R_L}$ for language $011(0+1)^*011$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

How do we find all equivalence classes of $\mathsf{R_L}$ for a language?

Say I'm trying to look for all equivalent classes for the regular language $\mathsf{L}$ is $011(0+1)^*011$.

Here's an example they give us in the book
http://books.google.com/books?id=VEHYzv0GHt8C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=ding+du+example+2.51&source=bl&ots=P8gAls0z7f&sig=HIsMb7rcD3hKZHYzi8fYZsyrLQ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5N0nUfSoJ6We2gWOv4HYDQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA

ps
The relation $\mathsf{R_L}$ is an equivalent relation.
$\mathsf{R_L}$ on $\Sigma^* as:$
$xRy$ iff $(\forall w)[xw \in \mathsf{L} \Leftrightarrow yw \in \mathsf{L}]$

Comment: What is $R_L$? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Equivalent Relation (also added to question)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Comment: Can you formulate your question properly? You haven't defined $R_L$. What is $L$? Is $L$ the language? Why not make these things explicit? Given a language $L$, define $R_L= ...$.

Comment: $011(0+1)^*011$ is the language

Comment: What is $L$? I'm simply asking to fix the question to define all of the ingredients ($L, R_L$) properly.

Comment: $\mathsf{L}$ Is the accepted language

Comment: Do you mean all regular expressions that define the same language?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant

Comment: I think that he's looking for a set of equivalent regular expressions in the sense that they accept the same languages and nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Please change the question, rather than just answering in comments.

Comment: Please edit the question. State the problem clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Is this clear enough? because it doesnt get more clear than that in my textbook

Comment: @saadtaame : what do you mean by "all regular expressions that define the same language"? There are infinitely many of those.

Comment: If you know what I mean, what's the point of asking? After all, I'm just trying to clarify what the OP is asking. Let $L=\{a\}$. There is only one regular expression for this language. How would you make infinitely many?

Comment: Because the OP responded that this is what he meant. I don't understand what that means (perhaps neither does the OP), but you offered this possibility, I wondered what you meant by it.

Comment: If you take a minimal DFA of some language and try all the possible ways of applying Arden's lemma, you will find a finite number of equivalent regular expressions for that language. That could serve as an algorithm.. and there are finitely many.

Comment: @saadtaame : First, it's a nice solution! As for your example - for a finite language of course there are only finitely many regexes. But for an infinite language there are infinitely many.

Comment: Guys im sorry for the confusion, but here's an example from the book (see edited question).
Hope that clarifies it

Comment: If you want to minimize a DFA, you should look for states that are equivalent (that's what the author means by equivalence classes). The number of equivalence classes is equal to the number of states in the minimal DFA. Watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLuuWJPBZXA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at Sipser's "Theory of Computation" for a full explanation.
Technically, you must first define the problem. What do you mean by "find the equivalence classes"? You probably mean that you want to find a representative of each class, or to find an algorithm that given a word, classifies it to a class.

Probably the easiest way to do so, is to construct a DFA for the language, and then minimize it. By the correctness proof of minimization, the states of the minimal DFA correspond to the equivalence classes.

EDIT: The example in the book doesn't show you how to find the equivalence classes algorithmically. It just shows an example of finding them based on intuition and clever thinking (as you would do with a general mathematical problem). There is no general way to do that.

What the example demonstrates is that if you find these classes, then you can construct a minimal DFA. The interesting point is that the converse is also true.

Comment: Looked at Sipser's but it wasn't as helpful...
Were actually using Ding-Zhu Du'sTheory of Computational Complexity

Comment: None the less, the answer is still valid. You can construct an NFA from the regular expression, determinize it using the subset-construction, and then minimize it using your favorite minimization algorithm (there are several).

Comment: I think you were right about constructing a DFA, that' might've been the step I was missing in the analysis